# Centrar jumbotron en página dinamicamente

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente jumbotron usando la plantilla AdminLTE cuando corro el menu lateral se ve bien de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando cuando el menu lateral esta en posicion normal (no colapsado) el jumbotron se pierde en la parte derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer que cada vez que colapse o no la barra lateral el jumbotron cambie de tamaño para que quede de forma centrada como en la imagen 1

**Codigo del jumbotron**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="center jumbotron">
            <h1>Bienvenidos</h1>
            <p>Sistema Gestor de Licores</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo que pudiéramos reproducir?

Comment: Ese trozo de código es correcto, el problema debe estar en el contenedor donde lo estás colocando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase ***center*** debe ir colocada en el contenedor no en el elemento, puesto que se centra el contenido del contenedor (valga la redundancia).

```
<div class="container center">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bienvenidos</h1>
        <p>Sistema Gestor de Licores</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no funciono, se sigue viendo igual

Comment: creo que lo que se esta desbordando no es tu jumbotron entonces es el contenedor del mismo debido a que le reduces el view width de la pantalla intenta hacer que el contenedor del jumbotron cambie el tamaño dinamicamente, trata de darle medidas relativas al tamaño del padre